# no roots in the disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that for any $R>0$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the polynomial
$$1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+ \ldots + \frac{z^{n}}{n!}$$
has no zeroes in the disc $|z|<R$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Hint: It converges uniformly to $e^z$ on disks.

Comment: @user44636: How will you start?

Answer (score 2):

T. Bonger's comment above suggests a less circuitous approach.

Note that if $|z| = R$, then $0 <e^{-R} \le |e^z|$. Let $p_n$ be the $n$th approximation to $z \mapsto e^z$ as in the question above. Choose $n$ large enough so that $\sup_{|z| = R} |e^z-p_n(z)| < e^{-R}$. The strict part is important here. Both $z \mapsto e^z$ and $p_n$ are entire, of course.

Now apply Rouche's theorem, if $|z|=R$, then
$|e^z-p_n(z)| < e^{-R} = |e^z|$. Hence $z \mapsto e^z$ and $p_n$ have the same number of zeroes in $B(0,R)$.

Comment: The classicist speaks.  I mean writes.  No, I mean types.  Live from the Caffe Mediterraneum, Beserkeley, CA.

Comment: @RobertLewis: I need to visit the Med soon! I'm happy to have hit 50k on Saint Patrick's day...

Comment: you keep saying/writing/typing that!  You'd better get your ass over here!

Comment: @RobertLewis: The breathalyzer might disagree :-).

Comment: Indeed!  Happy St. Paddy's; my breath is "green" tonight as well!  Not liquid green, though! ;-)!  Soon, I hope!

Comment: @RobertLewis: Lá Fhéile Pádraig Shona Duit!

Comment: "On top of old smokey . . . "  The Gaelic sounds nice!  What does it mean?  Uh-oh, here comes the comment heat!

Comment: @RobertLewis: Happy Saint Patrick's day in Irish!

Comment: @ copper.hat:  nice!  Caffe's closing, gotta go.  Soon, I hope!